# Why doesn't FTPWebRequest, or WebRequest in general accept a /../ path?

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to automate some upload/download tasks from an ftp web server. When I connect to the server through client, or through Firefox even, in order to get to my directory, I have to specify a path like this:

```
ftp://ftpserver.com/../AB00000/incoming/files
```

If I try to access this:

```
ftp://ftpserver.com/AB00000/incoming/files
```

The server throws an error that the directory does not exist. So, the problem:

I am trying to create an FTPWebRequest with the first ftp address, but it always parses out the "/../" part and then my server says the path doesn't exist.

I've tried these:

```
    Uri target = new Uri("ftp://ftpserver.com/../AB00000/incoming/files");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebReqeuest.Create(target);
```

and

```
string target = "ftp://ftpserver.com/../AB00000/incoming/files";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
```

In the first bit, the path is already incorrect when the Uri object is instantiated, in the second bit, it's after the WebRequest.Create method. Any ideas what's going on?

EDIT:

Additionally, since I posted this, I have tried creating the URI with the no parse option. I have also tried something like this:

```
string ftpserver = "ftp://ftpserver.com/../";
string path = "12345/01/01/file.toupload";

Uri = new Uri(ftpserver, path, true);
```

And it always parses out the root part ("/../").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try escaping the .. with something like:

```
Uri target = new Uri("ftp://ftpserver.com/%2E%2E/AB00000/incoming/files");
```

That works according to this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mariya/default.aspx) which I found in this [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/76d3a3a2-48b6-4753-988e-dfd845f582e9/).

Comment: That was it. Wow. The server chroots access to an ftpusers/user folder for each user, I have to login as an account that has access to all other user folders which is why the /../ has to be included.

Comment: Does this still work for you?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx

According the the reference above, when specifying an ftp url, the uri class should not compact the url.  For example, the following ftp url:

Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2E");
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);
Console.WriteLine(uri.PathAndQuery);

should result in:

AbsoluteUri:  "ftp://myUrl/%2E%2E/%2E%2E"
PathAndQuery: "/%2E%2E/%2E%2E"

But what I'm seeing is not what is expected:

AbsoluteUri:  "ftp://myUrl/"
PathAndQuery: "/"

Answer (score 3):

Not really sure about it, but it may be for security reasons, since allowing "/../" URIs would potentially let people navigate freely on any server's file system.

Also, the official [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) states that when resolving an URI one of the steps performed is actually the removal of "/../" segments, so it's not a problem in the C# library but it's regular URI behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the @ symbol like so?

```
Uri target = new Uri(@"ftp://ftpserver.com/../AB00000/incoming/files");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebReqeuest.Create(target);
```

Comment: Tried that, it does the same thing.

Comment: No characters in that string could be confused for escape characters, so making it a vertbatim string won't have any effect.