# C# Absolute URI removes ".." from URL

Tags: c#, ftp, urlencode, url-encoding

I have to upload a file via FTP to ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com

My root directory on remoteServer contains an "upload" and a "download" folder. I need to put my file in the "upload" directory.  But on log in, the server automatically puts me in the "download" folder.

I tried doing this:

```
string serverTarget = "ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com/";
serverTarget += "../upload/myfile.txt";
Uri target = new Uri(serverTarget);
FTPWebRequest ftp = (FTPWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(target);

using(Stream requestStream = ftp.GetRequestStream()) {
    // Do upload here
}
```

This code fails with: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)
I debugged the code, and `target.AbsoluteUri` returns as ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com/upload instead of ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com/../upload  (missing the ..)

If I put ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com/../upload in a browser, I can log in and verify this is the correct place where I want to put my file.

How can I get the FTPWebRequest to go to the correct place?

Comment: did you try @" instead of regular " for the expressions.

Comment: @LostInCode Essentially you're asking why ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com/../upload/myfile.txt is being displayed as ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com/upload/myfile.txt?  My guess is that /upload is already at the root of your site and that ../upload is seen as redundant.

Comment: @AndyEvans Unfortunately it isn't redundant - ftp.remoteServer.com only gets me to the download directory.  ftp.remoteServer.com/upload/ is interpreted as a folder inside the download directory

Comment: @AmitApollo Adding the @ did not help. :(

Comment: I believe this is a known issue. I've seen an article about it on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com). Unfortunately, I can't log in right now to find the issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can encode the dots as %2E to keep the dots in your URI.

So something like:

```
string serverTarget = "ftp://ftp.remoteServer.com/%2E%2E/upload/myfile.txt";
```

Comment: That did the trick! Once I know what to look for, I even found a previous SO entry on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480619/why-doesnt-ftpwebrequest-or-webrequest-in-general-accept-a-path

Comment: For FTP each Uri part may be constructed using Uri.EscapeDataString(fileOrFolderName) allowing all non Uri compatible character (spaces, unicode ...):

Comment: For example to allow any character in filename, use: req =(FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(path + "/" + Uri.EscapeDataString(filename)));

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string serverTarget = "../upload/myfile.txt";
Uri uri = new Uri(serverTarget, UriKind.Relative);
```

Answer (score 1):

Andy Evans' comment is correct.

Consider the URI: `http://ftp.myserver.com/../`. The `..` means, "take me to the parent of this directory". But there *is* no parent! So when you derive the absolute URL, you're going to end up with `http://ftp.myserver.com/` There is nothing else that the parser can do.

I think the problem is with the configuration of your FTP server. I assume that the directory structure looks something like:

```
ftproot
    upload
    download
```

It looks like the FTP service is automatically logging you to `/ftproot/download`. That is, the URI `ftp.myserver.com` gets mapped to `/ftproot/download` on the local file system. If that's the case, no amount of fiddling with the URI is going to get you anywhere. If the URI root is mapped to the download directory, there is no way you can, using the `..` syntax, "go up one level and then down."

Are you able to upload using an FTP client such as Filezilla, or perhaps the Windows FTP command line tool? If so, what are the steps you take to do it? Can you make your code do the same thing?